# How do I remove scroll from a nested div

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to fix my fixedDiv inside my Content div at the bottom, but when I am trying position as fixed and bottom as 0px, fixedDiv is going to the bottom of the entire body.

Note - All divs height are dynamic so absolute will not work.
Any solution will be much appreciated.

My HTML code -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "completeBody">
      <div class = "header">
      </div>
      <div class = "content">
        <div class = "content1">
        </div>
        <div class = "content2">
        </div>
        <div class = "content3">
        </div>
        <div class = "fixedDiv">
          This should be fixed to bottom of Content Div.
          Note height of all divs are dynamic in %tage.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS code -

```
/* Styles go here */

.completeBody
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.header
{
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.content
{
  height: 80%;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer
{
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.fixedDiv
{
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.content1
{
  height:250px;
  background-color: #303030 ;
}
.content2
{
  height:250px;
  background-color: #909090 ;
}
.content3
{
  height:250px;
  background-color: #D0D0D0 ;
}
```

Here is the link of Plunker -https://plnkr.co/edit/SEQ0Yur2Ybamcnu7dydz?p=preview

Comment: SO the content should be scrollable but the bottom element should stay in place at the bottom even if we scroll the content?

Answer (score 1):

OK since no-one answered correctly here's a simple / proper way to do it:

place your "bottom-fixed" element with `position:absolute; bottom:0;` but **not inside** the scrollable element, rather **inside it's parent wrapper**:

quick example:

```css
#wrapper{
  position:relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#scrollable{
  height:100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#bottomFixed{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scrollable"><p style="height:500px;">Long scrollable content...</p></div>  
  <div id="bottomFixed">Yey! I'm parent- fixed!!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Roko..its seemed to be a good option when the div is always visible there, but i need to hide and unhide the fixedDiv. I need fixedDiv to be in bottom of Content div and overlapping Content div. It will be visible only when user do some error.

Comment: @RHUL so? Hide it! and show it when needed. I don't understand your comment. It overlaps the content and it's bottom-fixed.

Comment: I'm sure the down voter misunderstood how to appy this to given code ... upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing relative/absolute positioning, your problem can be easily solved by:

```
.content
{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

`box-sizing:border-box;` Causes the element NOT to grow outside it's defined height/width.

`padding: 20px;` Whenever you apply `margin` the object will grow independent of the box-sizing, therefore in you case it is better to apply padding.

Comment: Why don't you recommend `relative` or `absolute` positioning?

Comment: As codebases grow complex having relative/absolute positioned components get harder to fix/debug when things go wrong, since we don't know what will go inside the `.content` div it is better to take an approach that won't cause having to mess with relative/absolute latter down the path :)

Comment: @ospfranco actually the WWW would be a much better place if all elements would've been `relative` (as opposed to `static`) from the beginning. And BTW there's nothing complicated in debugging relative / absolute.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan exactly, either all elements should be relative or all should be static, it is the mix of absolute and relative that makes things go out of place when you are on the 20th nested component. as for the complication I can only speak from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I tried working with your code and once I have removed the position:fixed the FixedDiv got inside the the content div and became in the bottom.

All I did is this:

```
.fixedDiv
{
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one part of a div to scroll and another to not, then you have to make two separate div inside your main div.
I have edited your code and corrected it. Hope this helps :)

```
.content
{
  height: 80%;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: none;
}
.content-main{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50%;
}

.content-second{
  overflow: none;
  height: 50%;
}
 <div class = "content">
    <div class="content-main">
      <div class = "content1">
      </div>
      <div class = "content2">
        content2
      </div>
      <div class = "content3">
        content3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-second">
      <div class = "fixedDiv">
        This should be fixed to bottom of Content Div.
        Note height of all divs are dynamic in %tage.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ahgcb44xpdDLVwi2uFBB?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Give this a shot!

```
.content{
    height: 80%;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
.fixedDiv{
    float: left; // or this
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

You can just use `float: left;`, and it will stick to the bottom! :)

This approach will also work on all versions of **Chrome**, **Safari**, **Firefox**, and **Edge** / **IE** 7^, and **Opera** 4^, e.t.c...

Comment: That's wrong. It will not be bottom-fixed! Have you tried your solution?

Comment: Correctly? The content area has scrollbars. Have you tested with scrollbars active? The "bottom" element will not stay bottom-fixed. (notice the `overflow:auto;`)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ah you're right! I did not notice that :) I will edit in a moment

Comment: Float left? What will not work either :) There's nothing into floating that could possibly fix an element to a scrollable parent bottom.

Comment: What does float:left have to do with align to bottom ?